# Map an arbitrary n-ary Tree with fold

Tags: javascript, haskell, tree, functional-programming, fold

I want to have some general purpose tools for dealing with trees. I'm using JavaScript, so there's little I can impose, and I'm using existing data structures that I can't change. I managed to define the following:

```
reduceTree :: (T a -> [T a]) -> (b -> T a -> b) -> b -> T a -> b
reduceTree(getChildren, f, accumulator, tree)
```

(I'm using Haskell type signatures because they're easier to read)

This `getChildren` function is required because my tree is arbitrary, and I know nothing about how it is constructed.

`reduceTree` works well. But I would like to have a `mapTree` function too, preferably reusing my `reduceTree` function, but I'm stuck. Something is amiss but I can't figure out what.

### Edit

My `reduceTree` implementation:

```
export function reduceTree(getChildren, f, accumulator, tree) {
  const children = getChildren(tree);
  if (!children || children.length === 0) {
    return f(accumulator, tree)
  } else {
    const childrenResult = children.reduce(
      (accumulator, subTree) => reduceTree(getChildren, f, accumulator, subTree),
      accumulator
    );
    return f(childrenResult, tree)
  }
}
```

It was tested and works.

(My pseudo Haskell implementation I used to construct/prove the javascript above:

```
reduceTree f a (Node val []) = f a val
reduceTree f a (Node val xs) = f (fold (reduceTree f) acc) val
```

)

Comment: Did you figure out the signature for `mapTree` already?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `reduceTree`, please? I would guess it currently does never call `f` - unless you change `getChildren` into something like `getContents :: T a -> (a, [T a])`.

Comment: Ah, it does - but your `f` should take an `a` parameter, not a `T a`.

Comment: @Bergi I avoid dealing with the structure of the nodes themselves by making `f :: b -> T a -> b`. Remember that I'm actually using javascript, so everything is pretty loose.

Comment: @WillNess, @Bergi I added my implementation of `reduceTree` and my pseudo code for it. Notice that my "Tree" only has Nodes with some value, and a (possibly empty) list of children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your tree data structure is defined as follows:

```hs
data T a = Node a [T a]
```

If that's the case then the fold for your tree data structure would be:

```hs
reduceTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> T a -> b
reduceTree f = let g (Node a xs) = f a (map g xs) in g
```

You can now define `mapTree` using `reduceTree` as follows:

```hs
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> T a -> T b
mapTree f = reduceTree (Node . f)
```

Converting it all to JavaScript:

```js
const Node = (a, xs) => ({a, xs});

const reduceTree = (f, node) => {
    const g = node => f(node.a, node.xs.map(g));
    return g(node);
};

const mapTree = (f, node) => reduceTree((a, xs) => Node(f(a), xs), node);

const tree = Node(2, [ Node(3, [ Node(11, [])
                               , Node(13, []) ])
                     , Node(5, [])
                     , Node(7, [ Node(17, [])
                               , Node(19, []) ]) ]);

console.log(mapTree(x => 2 * x, tree));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think `reduceTree` should have the signature `(a -> b -> b) -> T a -> b` - not a list of `b`s. Of course this definition fits better for your `map`.

Comment: No, a `Node` has a list of children. Each of those children need to be converted to a `b` in order for the `Node` to be converted to a `b`. It doesn't make sense to take exactly one `b` as an input. What if the `Node` doesn't have any children? From where would you conjure a `b`?

Comment: Oops, right, that `reduceTree` also misses a parameter for the initial value. You'd usually have `foldTree f acc (Node val children) = foldList (foldTree f) (f val acc) children)`

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something here but why do we need an initial value? Why do we need an accumulator at all? Also, by `foldList` I'm assuming that you mean `foldl` in Haskell right?

Comment: A generic `fold` function needs an initial value because there are foldable structures that are empty - unlike your representation of the n-ary tree that contains always at least one value in its root node.

Comment: Yes, `foldList` would be `foldl` or `foldr` in Haskell, I just used a different name to avoid the confusion from using the same overloaded function with different types.

Comment: Using `foldr` would restrict its type to `(a -> T a -> T a) -> T a -> T a -> T a` which is probably not what you'd want. Using `foldl` would allow its type to be `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> T a -> b`.

Comment: Yes, but `foldTree` isn't a generic fold. Also, your initial value keeps changing due to `foldList`. In fact, it changes from the get go due to `(f val acc)`. Just trying to understand what's the purpose of `acc` at all. To me, it doesn't seem like you'd need it.

Comment: Yes, folding the initial value with all the individual values from the tree is the entire purpose of a `fold` function, isn't it? Yes, the accumulator "changes" in the course of that.

Comment: @Bergi Haskell [has it the exact same way as here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:foldTree). John Hughes in his paper "Why Functional Programming Matters" [had it almost the same, as](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50418/5021) `foldTree :: (a -> b -> r) -> (r -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> r ; foldTree f g z (Node x t) = f x . foldr g z . map (foldTree f g z) $ t`. With it, `foldTree f g z = reduceTree (\a rs -> f a (foldr g z rs))` and `map h = reduceTree (Node . h) = reduceTree (\a rs -> Node (h a) rs) = foldTree (Node . h) (:) []`

Comment: @Bergi the absence of "zero" i.e. initial accumulator value comes from the absence of second clause in the data definition, `T a = Node a [T a]` a.o.t. lists' `List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`. So the algebra for the former is `NodeF a r -> r` where `data NodeF a r = NodeF a [r]`  and for the second it's `ConsF a r -> r` where `data ConsF a r = NilF | ConsF a r` (speaking in *recursion-schemes*). So there's no Nil case to handle.

Comment: @WillNess Haskell also has [`foldr` on those trees](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:foldr) :-)

Comment: @WillNess It's in the `Foldable Tree` instance

Comment: Thank y'all! I've ended up using your version, but everyone were very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Your pseudocode is broken. One way to fix it is

```js
reduceTree :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> T a -> b
reduceTree f acc (Node val []) = f acc val
reduceTree f acc (Node val ts) = 
    Data.List.foldl (\acc tree -> reduceTree f acc tree) (f acc val) ts
```

This means that your  Javascript  should have been

```js
export function reduceTree(getChildren, f, accumulator, tree) {
  const children = getChildren(tree);
  if (!children || children.length === 0) {
    return f(accumulator, tree)
  } else {
    const childrenResult = children.reduce(
      (accumulator, subTree) => reduceTree(getChildren, f, accumulator, subTree),
      f(accumulator,tree)  // referring to `tree` only for its stored node value, yes?
    );
    return childrenResult;
  }
}
```

Presumably Javascript's `reduce` on lists is a *left* fold (according to Wikipedia it is so).

It performs pre-order tree traversal, and is equivalent to the `tfoldl` function at the bottom of this post. Implementing `map` with it doesn't quite work though,

```js
tmap f t = reduceTree (\acc val -> Node (f val) ???) ??? t
```

because the types are not right for the `Node :: a -> [T a] -> T a`, which can't be made to fit the reducer type above, `b -> a -> b` (it needs the type  `a -> [b] -> b`).

This is because this kind of linear folding is essentially flattening the structure, treating it as a *linear* sequence.

Some extraneous elaborations follow.

---

Haskell [has it the exact same way](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:foldTree) as the `reduceTree` function in [Aadit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580167/849891).

John Hughes in his famous paper "Why Functional Programming Matters" had it almost the same way too, as

```js
foldTree :: (a -> b -> r) -> (r -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> r 
foldTree f g z (Node x t) = f x . foldr g z . map (foldTree f g z) $ t
```

He used an equivalent, but a bit more verbose formulation, which he called `redtree`, for "reduce tree". It holds that

```js
foldTree f g z = reduceTree (\a rs -> f a (foldr g z rs))
```

so the two are pretty much equivalent. Then,

```js
map h = reduceTree (Node . h) 
      = reduceTree (\a rs -> Node (h a) rs) 
      = foldTree (Node . h) (:) []
```

The absence of "zero" i.e. initial accumulator value comes from the absence of second clause in the data definition, `data T a = Node a [T a]` as opposed to `List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`, for the lists.

The fold's reducer function for the latter takes either `Nil` or `Cons a r` to `r`, hence it must have the "zero" i.e. defult value supplied to it; and for the former it  takes `Node a [r]` to `r`, so there's no `Nil` case to handle (cf. [recursion-schemes](/questions/tagged/recursion-schemes)).

---

Following [a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572451/map-an-arbitrary-n-ary-tree-with-fold/47580167?noredirect=1#comment82169164_47580167) from [user Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) in the comments, the Haskell package [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html) defines [a Foldable instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/src/Data.Tree.html#line-170) for this type,

```js
data T a = Node a [T a]
```

whose equivalent of `foldr` (with flipped arguments, for convenience), is

```js
tfoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> T a -> b -> b 
tfoldr f (Node x ts) z = f x $ Data.List.foldr ($) z [tfoldr f t | t <- ts]
```

indeed threading through the state / accumulator! It can be also written as

```js
tfoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> T a -> b -> b 
tfoldr f (Node x ts) z = f x . Data.List.foldr (.) id [tfoldr f t | t <- ts] $ z
```

whichever is easier for you to implement. This is implementing the post-order tree traversal; for the usual pre-order traversal use

```js
tfoldl :: (a -> b -> b) -> T a -> b -> b
tfoldl f (Node x ts) z = Data.List.foldr (>>>) id [tfoldl f t | t <- ts] $ f x z
                 -- // = tfoldl f tn (... (tfoldl f t2 (tfoldl f t1 (f x z))) ...)
```

where `(f >>> g) x = g (f x)`, or

```js
tfoldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> T a -> b -> b
tfoldl f (Node x ts) z = Data.List.foldr (>>>) id [tfoldl f t | t <- ts] $ f z x
                 -- // = tfoldl f tn (... (tfoldl f t2 (tfoldl f t1 (f z x))) ...)
```

which is  equivalent to the code at the start of this post, up to the order of arguments.

- see also: [Variations of folds on Haskell Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52451923/849891)

Comment: Thank you! That is some extremely helpful explanation, and it helped me a lot. I ended up using Aadit's solution, but I did not understand it before reading your answer.

Comment: @Luftzig thank you, and me too, before writing it. :) Interesting how one kind of a fold lets you recreate the structure easily, and the other destroys it. There's something like this in implementing `tail` with a right fold, which is very hard to do IIRC, and trivial with a paramorphism. there's some deeper currents here for sure...

Comment: re: linearity, it means it *is* easy to map a function over  node values *while* transforming a Tree into a List. It's just that the tree structure is lost in the process. Maybe it can be recovered by somehow decorating the output type of the reducer function with some "markings", and recreating the structure back, afterwards. --- the opposite question to ask oneself might be, is it possible to flatten a tree into a list with Aadit's fold.

Comment: @WillNess Maybe your `foldTree` aka `redtree` is too mundane but I consider it a functional pearl. The equivalence to Aadit's catamorphism isn't obvious to me, b/c it inlcudes a right fold and thus loses non-linear structure. But since `foldTree` has two distinct functions it can somehow retrieve the structure. It is an amazing combinator, thanks for digging it out of the paper.

Comment: @scriptum *John Hughes's* `foldTree`, I only tweaked it syntactically. :)  The paper presents it in a more verbose way, I was real proud of myself recognizing that pattern and putting that recursive call into the composition chain. :) it also features [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50417/most-concise-way-to-fold-tree-structures/50418#50418) BTW.  I do remember writing this answer, but not all the details about it. :)  I think you've put your finger on it, with the two functions distinction.