# Variations of folds on Haskell Trees

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, fold

Given a tree defined to be:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I want to use the function:

```
foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree _ b Leaf         = b
foldTree f b (Node lt x rt) = f (foldTree f b lt) x (foldTree f b rt)
```

To be able to create equivalents of the normal `foldr` and `foldl` as:

```
foldTreeR :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTreeL :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

I thought these would be fairly straightforward since their definitions mimic those of `foldr` and `foldl` pretty much exactly. I assumed that all I would have to do would be plug in the values analogously in a similar manner so I would write an anonymous function, an accumulator with the base state of my tree and the tree that needs to be processed. The lambda function would have to vary based on the type of fold being done.

Here is what I came up with:

```
foldTreeR :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTreeR f acc t =  foldTree (\x acc -> f x acc) acc t
```

I get the error:

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a -> b’ 
>       ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>         the type signature for:
>           foldTreeR :: forall a b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
>         at Folds.hs:294:14
>       Expected type: Tree (a -> b)
>         Actual type: Tree a
> ```

I am not really sure how I should pass in the original tree in this case.

It seems the left fold will just be a variation of the same with the values within the lambda function re-ordered as well as evaluated differently.

Could someone help me understand how a solution can be reached here?

Comment: `foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b` expects the first argument to be a function that takes 3 arguments. you've given it a function that takes 2 arguments. basically the error says it can't make a value (the result of `f x acc`) be a function (the expected result of a functions of type `b -> a -> (b -> b)`, which is equivalent to `b -> a -> b -> b`)

Comment: I understand that but I am not completely sure what I would pass in as the third value in this case. First would be the value from the tree it self, second would be the accumulator. What might the third one be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can recover the linear, accumulator-passing folds from the data type-following tree-shaped folds by folding into *endofunctions*, like this:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

-- foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b

foldTreeR :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> Tree a -> r
foldTreeR cons z t = foldTree g id t z           -- b ~ r -> r
  where
  g lt a rt = lt . cons a . rt
```

And the left fold:

```
foldTreeL :: (acc -> a -> acc) -> acc -> Tree a -> acc
foldTreeL conj z t = foldTree g id t z           -- b ~ acc -> acc
  where
  g lt a rt = rt . flip conj a . lt
```

---

More detailed explanations:

Both `cons a` and `flip conj a` have type `r -> r` (or `acc -> acc`, which is the same). This is the type of functions with the types of argument and result being the same.

Such functions are known as endofunctions, *endo* indicative of the sameness of their domain and codomain (the types on the right and left side of the arrow). As such, they *compose* easily: can participate in `(.)` operation, i.e. function composition, with the result of composition having the same type as the types of operands:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(f . g) x = f (g x)

-- and for endofunctions,
-- ((f :: r -> r) . (g :: r -> r)) :: r -> r
```

For a tree with an in-order traversal of `[a,b,c,...,n]`, the right fold turns that tree into a composition

```
(cons a . cons b . cons c . ..... . cons n) z

-- which is the same as
-- cons a (cons b (cons c ... (cons n z) ... ))
```

and the left fold turns it into

```
(conj' n . ..... . conj' c . conj' b . conj' a) z
```

where

```
conj' a acc = flip conj a acc = conj acc a     -- by definition of `flip`

-- so the above composition chain is the same as
-- conj (... (conj (conj (conj z a) b) c) ...) n
```

with some `id`s sprinkled around that chain, each `Leaf` being turned into an `id`, having no effect on the whole chain, because

```
(id . f) x = id (f x) = f x = f (id x) = (f . id) x
```

so

```
id . f = f = f . id
```

i.e. `id` serving as a 'zero' element w.r.t. to the function composition operation, just like `0` does with the `+` operation (this, by the way, is referred to as *'monoid'* being formed by `.` and `id`, or by `0` and `+`).

---

Here's how we'd create that in-order traversal list for a tree:

```
inorder :: Tree a -> [a]
inorder t = foldTree g [] t
  where
  g lt a rt = lt ++ [a] ++ rt
```

So the list `[a,b,...,n]` is actually created as

```
[] ++ [a] ++ [] ++ [b] ++ [] ++ ... ++ [n] ++ []
```

and the right fold of that tree would be created as

```
(id . cons a . id . cons b . id . .... . cons n . id) z
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could have come up with the solution yourself.

We have

```hs
data Tree a =                               Leaf 
            | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)                   deriving (Eq, Show)

foldTree :: (        b ->   a ->   b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b

foldTree    (g :: b ->   a ->   b -> b) (z :: b) :: Tree a -> b
```

So given `g` and `z` this function turns a `Tree a` value into a `b` value by turning the sub-trees of `t` into `b`s and combining them with the tree's `a`, through `g`.

Can we ***`map`*** over these trees, using `foldTree`? Yes:

```hs
mapTree :: (a -> c) -> Tree a -> Tree c
mapTree f t = foldTree g z t
  where
  -- we need to create a Node with the mapped element inside it
  -- already having the transformed sub-trees. Well, 
  -- creating Tree values is the job of that type's data constructors:
  g lt a rt = Node lt (f a) rt      -- f is applied to the element `a`
  -- and all leaves are transformed into the same value, which is:
  z = Leaf
```

So now we have `mapTree (f :: a -> c) :: Tree a -> Tree c`. How does this help us?

What do we want? We want

```hs
foldTreeR :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
-- i.e.
foldTreeR (cons :: a -> r -> r) (nil :: r) :: Tree a -> r
```

So we have `cons`, such that `cons (x :: a) :: r -> r`.

What if we *map this `cons`* over a Tree? The type `a -> r -> r` is actually `a -> (r -> r)`, and indeed we just saw that `cons` turns an `(x :: a)` into `r -> r` (*read it: turns a value `x` or type `a` into a value of type `r -> r`*):

```hs
mapTree (cons :: a -> r -> r) :: Tree a -> Tree (r -> r)
```

Why would we want *that*? What can we do with all those `r -> r` functions we now have in the tree's nodes? Well, we can turn a tree into a list of the values in its nodes, by an in-order traversal:

```hs
inorder :: Tree d -> [d]
inorder t = foldTree (\l a r -> l ++ a : r) [] t
```

so we can have

```hs
inorder . mapTree (cons :: a -> r -> r) :: [r -> r]
          -----------------
          Tree a -> Tree (r -> r)
--------
Tree (r->r) -> [r->r]
```

and we can *compose* all these functions inside that list, *linearly*, to arrange for the right-to-left  result-passing operation which *is* ... the *right fold!*

```hs
foldTreeR_ :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> Tree a -> r
foldTreeR_ cons z t = foldr ($) z (inorder $ mapTree cons t)
           -- or, equivalently,
           --         foldr (.) id (inorder $ mapTree cons t) z
```

That's it.

If we inline everything and simplify the resulting definitions, we get the one in the other answer.

Same for the left folding. Try it.